# How to lock one specific icon to a location on your desktop?

Tags: windows-7, desktop

I have one shortcut icon to a register that a update on a very regular basis that sits on my desktop in win7. I want to lock that icon so i know exactly where it is every time I flick to my desktop to access it. Some days sees me update this file up to 200 times and I get sick of looking for it. I also use the desktop a lot for temp file locations for short term files, hence the desktop changes by the minute or hour regularly.

What is my best option to instantly access this file for updates if I can not lock that one particular icon in place?

I do not want to use a program that restores set locations every time I want to access this file.

Comment: You can tell Windows to allow you to organize your the placement of the icons. I would do this.  So unless you "sort" your icons the placement would be where you put it.

Comment: Um, just leave the program running instead of closing it down.

Answer (score 1):

You can pin this icon to your task bar, that way you know exactly where it is each and every time.

Comment: Except the OP wants to lock it to their desktop.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Read the OP - it reads "What is my best option to instantly access this file for updates if I can not lock that one particular icon in place?" Therefore this answer is valid!

Answer (score 1):

> What is my best option to instantly access this file for updates if I
>   can not lock that one particular icon in place?

I don't know how to lock it but as an alternative why don't you use keyboard short cuts? Windows 7 allows you to create global short cuts which reference a program or a file. You don't even need to return to your desktop!

Create a shortcut to the program or file for which you want to create a keyboard shortcut!

Right-click the shortcut, and then click Properties.

In the Shortcut Properties dialog box, click the Shortcut tab, and then click the Shortcut key box.

Type in a letter or a number of your choice to create the shortcut. The shortcut works by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> + something. So, if you want to access this file by the number 1, then just press the number 1 and you will see the box auto-populates with CTRL + ALT + 1. The shortcut will be <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. If you want to access this file with the letter N then type N. The short cut will be <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If your using it that much, I would pin it to your start menu, that way you can get to it without having to reveal the desktop.

Technically I do not think it's possible to 'lock' something in place, without using 3rd party software like Stardock Fences.

Comment: Thanks guys, ended up flicking a shortcut to the taskbar, start menu and quicklaunch......see which one is the go after a week or so.